# git clone - fatal: remote error: access denied or repository not exported

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

When I try to perform the following command, `git clone git://github.com/mainDir/dirA`,  I get the following error:

```
> git clone git://github.com/mainDir/dirA
Cloning into 'dirA'...
fatal: remote error: access denied or repository not exported: /8/nw/87/1e/aa/2154553/2154553.git
```

`git://github.com/mainDir` is a `private repository`

If I try to use github for the mac... I see the message `Cannot find repository`.

For sure the problem is in my desktop (client part) because I know how to reproduce the problem:

1) `git clone repo` on my desktop (it works)
2) `rm -rf repo`
3) `git clone repo` and I get the error

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 13):

Is it actually a private repository?  If so, I don't believe that

```
git clone git://github.com/mainDir/dirA
```

will work.  Try

```
git clone git@github.com:mainDir/dirA
```

From [github help](http://help.github.com/remotes/):

> For public repos, the URL can be a read-only URL like git://github.com/user/repo.git or an HTTP read-only URL like http://github.com/user/repo.git. For public repos you own or are a collaborator on, and all private repos, you must use a private ssh url like git@github.com:user/repo.git.

Answer (score 4):

Just try using:

```
git clone http://github.com/mainDir/dirA
```

or

```
git clone https://github.com/mainDir/dirA
```

Answer (score 0):

Today this happened to me today when I removed my fork of a certain repo, which was detached from the upstream network a day before. And then I re-forked the upstream under the same account.

First, it was showing me

```
Forking org_name/repo_name
It should only take a few seconds.
```

longer than usual.

Then, it got stuck with

```
This repository is temporarily unavailable.
The backend storage is temporarily offline. Usually this means the storage server is undergoing maintenance. Please contact support if the problem persists.

Check our status site for updates
```

on the forked repo page.

So I removed it after a while, waited a few hours and forked again.

I think, this is some race condition happening because of GitHub's eventual consistency.

Comment: Probably yes, but back when I was checking it, it didn't show up there :)

Answer (score -1):

it's a different problem for real:

`git clone git://github.com/mainDir/dirA`

looks more like an attempt to clone only subfolder of the `mainDir` repository and GIT refuse this functionality for a reason to save the repository integrity. so clone instead:

`git clone git://github.com/mainDir`

then look for the subfolder required